# Solidity code that allows someone to input their yearly salary and get financial advice. I can't input salary and get result based on the input

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;
contract Artithmetic{

    uint256  yearlySalary = 250000 ;
    uint256  months = 12;
    uint256 conversionRate = 113;
    uint256 public  monthlySalary = yearlySalary / months * conversionRate;
    string public message = "Import a 2021 Audi A6";
    bool public youreRich = true;

    function updateYearlySalary(uint256 _yearlySalary) public{
        
        yearlySalary = _yearlySalary;
        
    }
    

    function financialAdvice() public {

        if(monthlySalary<=2000000){
            
            youreRich = false;
            message = "Buy assets that earn you passive income first!";
        }

    }}
```

I can't get the code to perform arithmetic that would change the financial advice based on the amount I input when I compile.

Comment: can you show the full error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write an additional function to set the monthly salary

```
uint256 public  monthlySalary;

function setMonthlySalary() public {
    monthlySalary= yearlySalary / months * conversionRate;
}
```

Update yearly salary first. call `updateYearlySalary`

then call `setMonthlySalary`

then call `financialAdvice`

Finally call `message` and it will be updated:

[image]

Comment: @MASAKAGENE  Plain "Thank you" does not work here sir :) If the answer helps, accept it, please.